# Logic for Shipping Rates and Taxes for an e-commerce site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm taxed with developing a custom e-commerce application for my company (using PHP/MySQL). The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to understand how most sites out there calculate their shipping rates. 
I've checked out OsCommerce cart, Opencart, etc. I even purchased an item on Amazon to see if I could understand the logic behind the shipping rates, but I couldn't on all those 3 applications. 
What's the actual problem I face? Do I calculate the shipping 
1) By flat rate or by weight? Since our company plans to license the framework to other companies who have shown interests in it, the products each site sell will be different; thus, different weights and sizes. Think of it as a minuscule version of Amazon. 
2) By destination location? Obviously, a customer purchasing an item 50 miles away wouldn't pay the same rate as someone 500 miles away. 
3) By any other ways I might have missed? 
If it'll help, we plan to use only shipping companies with tracking numbers, so our choice of shipping companies are narrowed down. 
If there's an article out to simplify my problem, I'll be happy to read it. 
We are developing it from scratch, so we aren't using any pre-existing framework

Comment: Use an API provided by one of the shipping agencies. They will accept a request in the form of POST/XML/JSON and will return data corresponding to the request.

Comment: Unless they're using something like USPS flat-rate boxes, they'll be querying FedEx/UPS/DHL directly to see what they'd charge in realtime.

Comment: And FedEx and UPS do supply API's to calculate postage/transit times - so that is another place that you can look. Usually, a lot of those sites will have a 'Developer' section that will provide that necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I stated earlier, if you use a major gateway for processing payments (Google Checkout, Authorize.Net, PayPal) they will supply ways to calculate the postage associated with an item.

Read this link as an example: http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Carrier_Calculated_Shipping.html

Comment: Really? So, instead of storing the shipping rates, taxes, etc in a database, PayPal has an API I can query to retrieve the shipping information for the particular item?

Comment: Yes. You don't think all these mom and pop type shops have someone coding all these values in a database do you? :)

Comment: Do you happen to have a direct link to the PayPal page? I've been checking PayPal's forum, and the closest thing I found to a shipping API is GetShippingAddress API. Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to sign up for an account with them to use it.

Comment: I know; I just need to read the API to understand the specification required. Thanks